# regex multiple matches with OR look behind

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string:

`'/photos/full/1/454/6454.jpg?20140521103415','/photos/full/2/452/54_2.jpg?20140521104743','/photos/full/3/254/C2454_3.jpg?20140521104744'`

What I want to parse is the address from `/` to the `?` but I can't seem to figure it out.

So far I have `/(?<=')[^?]*/` which will properly get the first link, but the second and third link will start with `,'/photos/full/...` <--notice that it starts with a `,'`

If I then try `/(?<=',')[^?]*/` I get the second and third link but miss the first link.

Rather than do 2 regexes, is there a way I can combine them to do 1? I've tried using `/((?<=')|(?<=',')[^?]*/ to no avail.

My code is of the form `matches = string.scan(regex)` and then I run a `match.each` block...

Comment: Anchor to beginning of string *or* comma: `/(?:^|,)...`  And capture `...\/([^\/?]+)\?`

Comment: FYI added sample code and explanation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby 2, which has `\K`, you can use this simple regex (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/nZ6sY3)):

```
'\K/[^?]+
```

To see all the matches:

```
regex = /'\K\/[^?]+/
subject.scan(regex) {|result|
# inspect result
}
```

**Explain Regex**

```
'                        # '\''
\K                       # 'Keep Out!' abandons what we have matched so far
\/                       # '/'
[^?]+                    # any character except: '?' (1 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: thanks, 1 thing though your first `'\K/[^?]+` needs to escape the forward slash

Comment: @Chowza Thank you, glad it works! Regarding the `/`, it is already escaped in the Ruby code sample. But as a pure regex, the `/` doesn't need to be escaped, and is usually presented this way. (The reason we escape the `/` in Ruby is that it's used as a delimiter.)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about `\K`. +1

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the +1, for some reason someone must have unvoted the answer at the same time so that makes up for it. :) Yes `\K` is terrific. It's available in Perl, PCRE and Ruby 2.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
(?<=,|^)'\K[^?]+
```

Where `(?<=,|^)` checks that the quote is preceded with a comma or the start of the string/line. And where `\K` removes all on the left (the comma here) from the match result.

or more simple:

```
[^?']+(?=\?)
```

all that is not a quote or a question mark followed by a question mark.

Comment: Nearly simultaneous and identical answer—it's only fair to share the love!... +1 :)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about `\K`. +1

Answer (score 0):

One can simply use a positive lookahead and non-greedy operator, and this of course is not limited to v2.0:

```
str.scan(/(?<=')\/.*?(?=\?)/)
  #=> ["/photos/full/1/454/6454.jpg",
  #    "/photos/full/2/452/54_2.jpg",
  #    "/photos/full/3/254/C2454_3.jpg"]
```

Edit: I added a positive lookbehined for the single quote.  See comments.

Comment: Hey Cary, that was a good simple way... But it seems that being preceded by a quote was an important part of his spec. :)